# Add URL Parameters to the DuckDuckGo searchplugin for Firefox

Tags: xml, firefox, parameters, search-engine, opensearch

Here is the xml file for a basic https query to DuckDuckGo:

```
<SearchPlugin xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/" xmlns:os="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
<os:ShortName>Duck Duck Go (SSL)</os:ShortName>
<os:Description>Search Duck Duck Go (SSL)</os:Description>
<os:InputEncoding>UTF-8</os:InputEncoding>
<os:Image width="16" height="16">data:image/x-icon;base64,[*redacted image code*]</os:Image>
<os:Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="https://duckduckgo.com/?q={searchTerms}">
</os:Url>
</SearchPlugin>
```

I want to have certain parameters (namely, kb=-1 and kg=p ([link](https://duckduckgo.com/params.html))) append to a search that's performed through Firefox's search box. I've tried adding it using "`<Param name="paramName1" value="paramValue1"/>`" but that doesn't work.

Also, although adding kg=p will make all subsequent requests using POST (rather than GET), how can I make the initial one a POST request. I tried changing method="GET" to "POST", but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
<os:Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="https://duckduckgo.com/?paramName1=paramValue1&amp;q={searchTerms}">
```

Use `&amp;` for all occurrences of `&` that would separate parameters, and URL-encode other characters.

Answer (score 1):

I find a way in the latest version of firefox :
Windows 10 & Firefox 40.0.3

- Close all sessions of firefox.
- Eventually delete `C:\Users\"¤¤"\Appdata\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\"¤¤"\search.json` (if you do this you have to restart and close again firefox before continue to recreate a clean search.json)
- Edit the file `search.json`
- Find "`https://duckduckgo.com/`" (for me at the End Of File)
- Replace `https://duckduckgo.com/` by your own URL parameters like this : `https://duckduckgo.com/?kae=d&kak=-1&kf=fw`
- add the char "`&`" at then end of parameters like this : `https://duckduckgo.com/?kae=d&kak=-1&kf=fw&`
- Save file
- Restart Firefox

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know since when but if you want to do this, the solution consist to edit the file `search.json`. You will find this one in your `profile folder` of Firefox.

Inside this file, look for this :

```
"_urls":
    [{
        "template": "https://duckduckgo.com/?q={searchTerms}",
        "rels": [],
        "params": []
    },
    {
        "template": "https://ac.duckduckgo.com/ac/?q={searchTerms}&type=list",
        "rels": [],
        "type": "application/x-suggestions+json",
        "params": []
    }],
```

Once you have find it, add your parameters by editing the (first one) template like that :

```
"_urls":
    [{
        "template": "https://duckduckgo.com/?km=m&q={searchTerms}",
        "rels": [],
        "params": []
    },
```

In this example, I have add `km=m`. This parameter `km`change the disposal of the result. Instead to be on the left, now there will be centered. Also, don't forget to add `&` between [each parameters](https://duckduckgo.com/params) your want.
Once you have done, save the file `search.json` and reboot Firefox.

This work fine with the version 29 of Firefox.